# Yii2+Codeception: How to test sending messages via another mailer component?

Tags: yii2, codeception

I have two different `swiftmailer` instances in `Yii::$app` named as `mailer` and `feedback`. Codeception can catch only `mailer` component so sending via `feedback` is untestable by the right way.

Ok, I tried to get round it by using following code:

```
protected function _before()
{
    $components = Yii::$app->getComponents();
    $components['feedback']['class'] =
            \Codeception\Lib\Connector\Yii2\TestMailer::class;
    Yii::$app->set('mailer', $components['feedback']);
}
```

But messages still appear in `fileTransportPath` directory and test still fails with `Failed asserting that an array is not empty` (It not happens if I run tests with usual `mailer` component).

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we must mock another mailer component with `\Codeception\Lib\Connector\Yii2\TestMailer`:

```
protected function _before()
{
    $components = \Yii::$app->getComponents();
    $components['feedback']['class'] =
            \Codeception\Lib\Connector\Yii2\TestMailer::class;
    \Yii::$app->set('feedback', \Yii::createObject($components['feedback']));
}
```

Then we can test it:

```
public function testSendSuccess()
{
    //sending
    $result = \Yii::$app->feedback->compose()->setTextBody('sometext')->->setSubject('somesubject')->send();

    $this->assertTrue($result);

    //get sent message from memory
    $mailer   = $this->tester->grabComponent('feedback');
    $messages = $mailer->getSentMessages();
    $this->assertNotEmpty($messages, 'emails were sent');
    $emailMessage = end($messages);

    $this->assertInstanceOf(\yii\mail\MessageInterface::class, $emailMessage);
    expect($emailMessage->getTo())->hasKey(\Yii::$app->feedback->messageConfig['to']);
    expect($emailMessage->getFrom())->hasKey(\Yii::$app->feedback->messageConfig['from']);
    expect($emailMessage->getSubject())->contains('somesubject');
}
```

This works fine.